# getting currentRowindex how i get start time and end time

Tags: jquery

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/6/)

this is my jsfiddle getting currentRowindex how i get start time and end time.
                    user can drag on class(7th,8th,9th..)cells and select time.User has restricted to Not select  more than 3 cells
                    I am getting currentRowindex.how can i get time using rowIndex.

```
 var currentRow1 = $('.csstdhighlight').closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;
```

Comment: well you already done the hard part of it what you need is getting your selected row index start searching for second column value then add it to your first column value which you can find a few rows back from your chosen row.. then make a function that choses highest and lowest values.

Comment: can you try this http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/23/

Comment: not see where u get start time and end time can u show in alert box on click of buuttn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is a dirty coding but solves your problem..

```
firstMin = $(".csstdhighlight").closest('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var firstResult = $('#tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex-i).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
    if(firstResult !="") {
        firstHour = firstResult.replace(":00AM","").replace(":00PM","").trim();
    }
}
lastMin = $('#tableAppointment tr').eq(lastRow).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var lastResult = $('#tableAppointment tr').eq(lastRow-i).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
    if(lastResult !="") {
        lastHour = lastResult.replace(":00AM","").replace(":00PM","").trim();
    }
}
alert("[" + firstHour + ":" + firstMin + "] - [" + lastHour + ":" + lastMin + "]");
```

played on your demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/Ybp4m/

you can evolve it by your needs from here..

Comment: ya you r going corect way but not getting start time and end time

Comment: Format be this Start time="12:30:00"  End time="12:45:00" for one cell selection and for two cell selection 12:30:00 to 01:00:00 and for 3 cell selection 12:30:00 to 01:15:00